# Sending a chat message in GAE doesn't work

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp

I am trying to send out a simple Chat message to myself from a GAE Python app following the example in this [GAE document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/).

My code on the /chat postback is simply:

```
class Chat(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    message = self.request.get('content')
    status_code = xmpp.send_message("xxxxx@gmail.com", message)
    self.response.write("<html><body><p>Message: %s</p><p>Status Code: %i</p></body></html>" 
      % (message, status_code))
```

The code is deployed at http:http://mindful-braid-368.appspot.com where you can test it out. Each time the status code returned is 0, but no message is received at my Google account (xxxxx@gmail.com).

Is the example in the GAE document complete?  Is there anything else I must set up to send Chat/Talk/Hangouts messages?

Comment: google disconnected gmail from xmpp I'm afraid.

Comment: this functionality works fine when sending to non-gmail addresses. Try it.

Comment: Are you saying this feature does not work for all Google Accounts connected to Chat/Talk/Hangouts?

Comment: no, I'm saying that when running a GAE application that you can't use this to send messages to IM accounts based on gmail. create a new XMPP account on a non-gmail system and try sending it a message.

Comment: Oh. I only wanted to send to a Gtalk user. Is there a way to accomplish this? Is there a special email address format where I can use to deliver Gtalk messages? I notice that I can reply to an SMS sent to my Google Voice number by replying to the email address seen in the message log. That email address has the form 1mmmmmmmmm.1nnnnnnnnnn.jCBtkBvg-@txt.voice.google.com, where mmmmmm is my GV number and nnnn is the original sender's phone number. Is there a similar way for Talk/Chat/Hangouts messages?

Comment: ask a new question :)